# why is sys.stdin.read(4).encode('utf-8') returning more than 4 bytes?

Tags: python

I am passing a JSON object from Chrome to my Python app's stdin via the Chrome/JavaScript sendNativeMessage function.

Sometimes, the below code works.   Other times (I believe on larger messages), it does not work.   I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I will say that sometimes sys.stdin.read(4).encode('utf-8') seems to read 7 bytes instead of the specified 4 bytes, and that's when it breaks with a "struct.error: unpack requires a byte object of length 4" message.

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
# On Windows, the default I/O mode is O_TEXT. Set this to O_BINARY
# to avoid unwanted modifications of the input/output streams.
import os, msvcrt
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

# Read the message length (first 4 bytes).
#for line in sys.stdin:
text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.read(4).encode('utf-8')

logging.info( text_length_bytes )

# Unpack message length as 4 byte integer.
text_length = struct.unpack('i', text_length_bytes)[0]

logging.info( text_length )

# Read the text of the message.
text = json.loads( sys.stdin.read(text_length) )
```

Comment: Non-ASCII characters don't encode as single bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: Should I be encoding these a different way?   Or handling the data in a completely different manner?  I'm a bit lost on this one - apologies; I'm newer to Python.

Comment: @flatsix81: If you have a packed integer in there, you definitely don't want to be doing any encoding/decoding on the string that contains the packed integer. Read the raw bytes, as tommi suggests, then unpack it, then read the rest of the message, then *decode* (i.e. convert bytes into unicode) using utf-8 if they were *encoded* (i.e. unicode converted into bytes) using utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Unicode character may consist of more than one byte:

```
In [4]: len('ü'.encode('utf-8'))
Out[4]: 2
```

As you want to decode those 4 bytes as integer, you probably want to read them as bytes (instead of str) from stdin in the first place:

```
In [8]: type(sys.stdin.read(4))
aoeu
Out[8]: str

In [9]: type(sys.stdin.buffer.read(4))
aoeu
Out[9]: bytes
```

Comment: That worked!  Amazing.   I've been hitting my head against the desk for hours trying to resolve this.    Thanks again!